# How do i create a Json from a vfp table?

Tags: json, foxpro

I have an issue trying to create a json like txt file so i can use in in API link but i cant get the products coming in records. there are only 2 records in that temp table. why does the records duplicate in the ItemDetails object?

```
{
Close All

lcCRLF = Chr(13)+Chr(10)
local krec,i
Use temp In 0
Select temp
Go Top

orec=1
i=1
SCAN
krec=Recno()
     Scatter Memvar
     kstockcode=stockcode
     Strtofile(['{"CallBackUrl":"http://192.168.0.5:8128/kekaapi/invoices",]+lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .F.)
     Strtofile(["InvoiceNumber":,] +'"'+Alltrim(m.docno)+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile(["TotalInvoiceAmount":,] +'"'+Alltrim(Str(m.amount))+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile(["TotalDiscount":,] +'"'+Alltrim(Str(m.discamt))+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile(["PINOfBuyer":,] +'P001244574Q'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile(["HeaderFields":] +'{'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)

     Strtofile([        "Header1": "",] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile([        "Header2": "",] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile([        "Header3": "",] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile([        "Header4": "",] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile([        "Header5": "",] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Strtofile([   },] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     **----------------Item details
     Strtofile(["ItemDetails":] +'[{ "HSCode"'+":"+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     for i=1 to RECCOUNT()
          Strtofile([                              "ItemCode":,] +'"'+Alltrim(m.stockcode)+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .t.)
          Strtofile([                              "Description":,] +'"'+Alltrim(m.desc)+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
          Strtofile([                              "UnitInclPrice":,] +'"'+Alltrim(Str(m.unitprice))+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
          Strtofile([                              "UnitDiscount":,] +'"'+Alltrim(Str(m.discamt))+'"'+','+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
          Strtofile([                  },] +''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
         krec=krec+1     
     NEXT
     Strtofile([} ]+''+ lcCRLF, [c:\json.txt], .T.)
     Select temp
     
Endscan
Modify File c:\json.txt
}
```

Comment: See Marco Plaza's great `nfJson` tool https://github.com/VFPX/nfJson

Comment: Marco posted a lot about it at foxite.com: https://www.foxite.com/search.aspx?q=nfjson&o=1&s=0&e=0

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues.

In the ItemDetails section you have the for loop:

for i=1 to RECCOUNT().

RECCOUNT() gives you the number of rows in your table, so if your table has 2 rows, you'll get 2 sets of ItemDetails. As the SCATTER MEMVAR command is outside the for loop, the contents of the MEMVARs (m.StockCode etc) won't change, so you'll get 2 copies of the same values. If you only want 1 set of ItemDetails, remove the for loop. If you want multiple ItemDetails, you'll need to get them into the MEMVARs within the for loop.

When the SCAN loops to the 2nd table row, the first call to StrToFile() has .F. as the last parameter so it overwrites the file c:\json.txt. This file then gets recreated with the new rows values.

So I would expect the file to contain the values of the last record in the table with the ItemDetails duplicated for every record in the table(but the values will be from the last row values).

The solution is to move the first StrToFile() call BEFORE the SCAN (if you want CallBackUrl row) or change the .F. to .T. and add code to delete the file before the SCAN (if you want a CallBackUrl line for each row).

I suspect you want the last call to StrToFile() after the ENDSCAN too.

Hope this helps.